# I dont see any files

Tags: powershell, ftp

Broke the brain, but I do not understand what is wrong.I have code:

```
Import-Module PSFTP
$FTPServer = 'some ftp'
$FTPUsername = 'login'
$FTPPassword = 'password'
$locpath = "D:\test"
$date = Get-Date
$FTPSecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $FTPPassword -asPlainText -Force
$FTPCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($FTPUsername,$FTPSecurePassword)
Set-FTPConnection -Credentials $FTPCredential -Server $FTPServer -ignoreCert -Session MySession -UseBinary -UsePassive  
$Session = Get-FTPConnection -Session MySession 
$ftp= Get-FTPChildItem -Session $Session -Recurse
$loc= gci $locpath -Recurse
Compare-Object ($ftp) ($loc) -Property Name | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} | ForEach-Object { 
    $lastfile=$_.Name
    Get-FTPItem -Session $Session $lastfile  -LocalPath $locpath
}
```

When you call the variable `$ftp`, I see the following

```
PS C:\Users\test> $ftp

   Parent: ftp://some ftp

Dir Right     Ln  User   Group  Size   ModifiedDate        Name                                                                                                          
--- -----     --  ----   -----  ----   ------------        ----                                                                                                          
-                               B                                                                                                                                        
-                               B
```

Why I don’t see the files and the size of the files (by the way, the script for this does not copy files)

Comment: Examples [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-FTP-Client-db6fe0cb) supply a remote path for `Get-FtpChildItem.`

Comment: I'm catching on.But this script works on one FTP without problems, and this he does not give a list of files.Examples I watched and changed the configuration to different - result one.